# MS Graph Api call drops "The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood."

Tags: c#, exception, microsoft-graph-api, token

Using the following code drops an exception with the following message: "NoPermissionsInAccessToken The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood."

```
var clientId = "<GUID-goes-here>";  
var tenantId = "<GUID-comes-here>";  
var clientSecret = "<secret-goes-here>";
var scopes = new[] {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"};
var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder  
    .Create(clientId) 
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)          
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .Build();  
var authResult = confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
string token = authResult.AccessToken;

var authenticationProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) => {
    request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    await Task.FromResult<object>(null);
});

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

var queryOptions1 = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("startDateTime", "2020-05-16" ),
    new QueryOption("endDateTime", "2020-05-21"),
};

var calendar = graphClient.Me.Calendar.CalendarView
    .Request(queryOptions1)
    .OrderBy("start/dateTime")
    .Top(3)
    .GetAsync()
    .Result;
// DROPS
// ServiceException: Code: NoPermissionsInAccessToken
// Message: The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.
```

The app is registered, Calendars.Read, Calendars.Read.Shared permissions are granted. The token value seems to be good - about 1400 chars long.

Anyone any idea whats going on here? Any advice is welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using the Client Credential flow and you need to specify Application permissions for this so that they can showup in the token.

You can simply parse the token by putting it in https://jwt.ms and see if you have the permissions in your token or not.

There is one more thing that you miss here is that you are using `me` in the code which means there should be a user some how to login here but there is no user because you are using the App context flow. So simply add Application permissions and then call the API as below.

```
var calendarView = await graphClient.Users["userid"].CalendarView
    .Request( queryOptions )
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Replaced .Me to .Users["<guid>"] which was viewed from graph api call on Graph Explorer. Should be good. But nothing changed. Then I upload my token to jws.ms, decoded correctly, I didn't see any application permission included to the token. On Azure portal I already added application permissions to read my calendar before. What I miss?

Comment: As far as I see the url where the request is directed is "https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/users/<USERGUID>/calendar/calendarView".

Comment: Have you given the Admin consent?

Comment: Do not really know what are you talking about sire. :( Do you mean the azure admin should approve the application? https://i.imgur.com/nd3alsC.png it says needs no admin consent.

Comment: You are adding the delegated permissions. Please add application permissions with admin consent. See https://imgur.com/VUfrZfn

Comment: Ohh I see now. I will try it, but I am not the admin, so must wait his part to finish as well. I will come back soon...

Comment: Got the permissions from the Azure admin now, and the app works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Now I have another question: if I add only delegated permissions, this means the app can read only my calendars if I understood well - then how to "login" to achieve that? What is the difference in the app?

Comment: The first and foremost thing we need to see here is how are getting the token, if it's an app token then it takes only Application permissions inside it and doesn't care about delegated. If you are using User token then it will pick only delegated permissions. In your scenario you are using app token which takes only Application permissions and it doesn't know what `me` is because there is no user. So rather than using 'me' we should see who the user is using users/userid